# Making a custom bullet in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a list of student links that leads to their profile, so instead of the normal circular bullet points, I wanted smiley faces. The picture is 14x14. What can I do to make the bullets show up using only CSS?

```
ul {
  list-style-type:url(smiley.tiff);
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Check to make sure the image path is correct

Comment: Can't use `uri` with `list-style-type`, should use `list-style-image`

Answer (score 4):

Use a CSS background. `list-style-image` does not give you positioning options and often looks awful. Adjust the pixel values accordingly for your layout.

```
li.icon {
     background-image:url(...);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-position:3px 3px;
     min-height:16px;
     padding-left:20px;
}
```

BTW - don't use a TIFF (and TIFF is not supported by all browsers), the file will likely be HUGE. Covert it to a PNG.

Comment: I'm with this one. You get more control.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [list-style-image CSS rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-image) instead. And also, surround the url in quotes just in case; most browsers interpret it correctly without them, but it's good practice.

```
list-style-image: url('smiley.tiff');
```

Comment: @user2635429 You used it inside the `ul` element, right? Try `li { background: url('smiley.tiff') no-repeat left center; }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way this can be done is by setting:

```
ul { 
  list-style-image: url(‘images/sample-bullet.png’)
}
```

This way you can choose any image you want. There is a great article about **bullet styles** I think you could benefit from [here](https://kolosek.com/css-bullet-style/).

Answer (score -3):

just simple use font awesome , make the list-style:none and use font awesome icon simple 
Happy Coding :D